# Force open CSV with Column Data Format = TEXT in Excel (Powershell)

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, formatting

I have this CSV file I generate using Export-CSV. Everything is fine with it but it display like this when opening in Excel because the cells are not formatted as TEXT: [image]

I want to force open the CSV with the cells all set to TEXT like you can do manually with the interface.

[image]

Is there a way to automate that with PowerShell, opening the CSV in Excel with cells formatted as text?

Comment: Not sure if it will do what you want, but certainly worth taking a look at the [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel) module as it's the most featured module for Excel.

Comment: you CANNOT format a CSV file [beyond the delimiter used]. that is part of the definition of a CSV file. [*grin*] to format the file, you will have to do that in the import step via COM automation, OR do as @JamesC. recommends and use one of the PoSh Excel modules that can generate an excel file instead of a CSV file.

Comment: Thanks guys i'll use the module!

Comment: @lee_daily, would it be possible to do it with com automation though ? Having the CSV opened with text formatting for cells ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a very good way to make it happen!

After generating your CSV file, here is how to automatically load it into Excel with AutoFit column width and TEXT format for cells :) :

```
$Fichier = "PATH_TO_CSV.csv"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($Fichier)
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.worksheets.item(1)

$objExcel.Visible = $true

$Range = $worksheet.UsedRange.Cells
$range.NumberFormat = "@"

$WorkSheet.Columns("A:B").AutoFit()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a little trick you can use - convert your data to html, and save with "xls" extention. For example:

```
Get-Process | convertto-html | Out-File csv2.xls
```

You'll see a warning when opening it, just click OK.

You can suppress that warning message by adding extra key in registry:

open regedit

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Excel\Security

Create a new DWORD with name ExtensionHardening and value 0